# Hbase to Cassandra Migration Feasibility

Tags: cassandra

Is it feasible to migrate from Hbase to Cassandra?
If so, Could you please assist with steps to migrate from Hbase to Cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to migrate data into a Cassandra database is by exporting the data from the source into CSV files.

Once you have the CSV files, you can bulk-load them into Cassandra tables using the **[DataStax Bulk Loader (DSBulk)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkAbout.html)** tool.

Here are some references with examples to help you get started quickly:

- Blog - [DSBulk Intro + Loading data](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading)
- Blog - [More DSBulk Loading examples](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading)
- Blog - [Counting records with DSBulk `count`](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting)
- Docs - [Loading data examples](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/dsbulkLoad.html)

You can use the `count` command I linked above to check how many records were bulk-loaded as a way of verifying that it worked. DSBulk is open-source so it's free to use. Cheers!

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck with the migration. Cheers!